Why doesn't mass accumulate on surfaces like charge does?
When calculating the total charge of a body, one should not only take into account the charges inside it but also those located on its surface, such that:
$$Q=\int_V\rho dV + \int_\Omega\sigma dA$$
Nonetheless, when calculating the total mass of an object, I have never seen a surface term, and the calculation to be carried out is simply:
$$M = \int_V\rho dV$$
How come such similar properties of matter as charge and mass present this difference? Is there some situation in which one should take into account "surface mass density", if that's even a thing?

I'm not sure why you'd include a surface term if the volume integral includes the surface as a boundary for the charged case.

Mass sure seems to keep being added to my surface over time. Sigh.

Think about it: charges are subjected to strong electromagnetic forces pushing them apart, leading to significant accumulation at the surfaces. Masses don't ever do that. Worse, they pull at each other, so the centre tends to be higher density than the rest.

Are you thinking that electrons accumulate on the surface of a charged conductor, and electrons have mass? The mass of a proton is about $1800$ times bigger than that of an electron. Furthermore, it takes very few electrons to make a significant charge. The mass of the accumulated electrons is insignificant.

I think the heart of your question is the prevalence of charge separation and transport over mass transport in the presence of external fields.
First, as pointed out in the comments, $\int_V\rho dV$ calculates the total charge present in the object volume, which includes surface charges.
If we consider the surface charge density as $\sigma$ and account for the remaining charge in the volume through $\rho_0$, then
$$Q = \int_V\rho_0 dV + \int_\Omega \sigma dA$$
indicates charge separation and possible transport to the surface from the inner volume. The weaker the binding of electrons to the atoms, the larger the separation. This is an important phenomenon in polarizable materials (dielectrics) and conductors, applied in things like supercapacitors and Faraday cages.
Majority of the atom's mass is carried by the nucleus. Nucleons are about $10^4$ times heavier and hence move faster than a proton with the same momentum. Therefore, we tend to consider the nuclei as stationary while studying electronic motion, known as the Born-Oppenheimer approximation. So at typical energy scales, external driving forces cause faster electron movement than in nuclei. So you get appreciable spatial variation in charge density as compared to mass density.
This does not mean that mass transport rarely occurs. While atoms are tightly bound to each other in solids, great opportunities for mass transport are seen in liquids and indeed, concentration gradients of ions in solutions are key to functioning of electrolytes in batteries like SEI, dendrite formation. If you were analyzing mass transport in close to the electrode-electrolyte interface, it might be pertinent to then consider $$M = \sum_{z_i}\int_\Omega \sigma_{m_{z_i}}dA + M'$$ to study relevant ionic flows $z_i$ only and abstract all other materials as being 'inert'.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Charges repel (in this context). Mass attracts.
If you positively charge a body, all the individual charges will try to move away from other positive charges, resulting in all of them ending up on the surface. With mass, because it's attractive, it's the center of the body that gets denser (assuming the gravitational force is large enough to overpower intermolecular repulsion). This is covered in the volume integral.
